# No certificate in X-ARR-ClientCert header when called from Azure API Management

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-web-app-service, azure-api-management

I have configured an Azure website (with one [ApiController](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.apicontroller.aspx)) to use client-certificate authentication using the instructions provided [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-web-configure-tls-mutual-auth/). Summarizing: you set the `clientCertEnabled` flag to `true` and from then on your website starts asking for a client-authentication-certificate.

Works great, however, now I want to access the client certificate that is sent to the server. According to the MSDN article, it should be available in the `X-ARR-ClientCert` request header, except that it isn't!!

This means that *anyone* with a client-authentication-certificate can access my API, which is undesirable in my case.

So how do I retrieve the client-authentication-certificate that a client sends to my Web API?

**UPDATE 1**: I'm actually calling my API through [Azure API Management](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/api-management/). I configured APIM with my client-authentication-certificate and APIM calls my API without issues. However, when the API is called from APIM, no X-ARR-ClientCert header is set. When called directly via Fiddler, I do see the header. So APIM is calling my API in some different way?!?

**UPDATE 2**: I went through everything again and produced some logging. First the relevant part of the [`DelegatingHandler`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.delegatinghandler(v=vs.110).aspx) class I'm logging from:

```
protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage>
    SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
  Trace.TraceInformation("Going to validate client certificate.");

  var x509Certificate2 = request.GetClientCertificate();
  Trace.TraceInformation("Client cert: {0}", x509Certificate2 == null
    ? "<null>"
    : x509Certificate2.Subject);

  try
  {
    var headerKeys = string.Join("|", request.Headers.Select(h => h.Key));
    Trace.TraceInformation("Header keys: {0}", headerKeys);
  ...
```

And the resulting log output:

```
2015-12-07T08:08:24  PID[8464] Information Going to validate client certificate.
2015-12-07T08:08:24  PID[8464] Information Client cert: <null>
2015-12-07T08:08:24  PID[8464] Information Header keys:
  Connection|Host|Max-Forwards|Conf-Organisation-Key|Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key|
  X-Forwarded-For|X-LiveUpgrade|X-ARR-LOG-ID|DISGUISED-HOST|X-SITE-DEPLOYMENT-ID|
  X-Original-URL
```

So there's no client certificate and also no `X-ARR-ClientCert` header.

**UPDATE 3**: And here's the log that results when I go to my actual API directly with a client-authentication-certificate:

```
2015-12-07T09:16:45  PID[8464] Information Going to validate client certificate.
2015-12-07T09:16:45  PID[8464] Information Client cert: CN=rwildenberg@itq.nl
2015-12-07T09:16:45  PID[8464] Information Header keys:
  Connection|Accept|Accept-Encoding|Accept-Language|Cookie|Host|Max-Forwards|
  User-Agent|Upgrade-Insecure-Requests|DNT|X-LiveUpgrade|X-ARR-LOG-ID|DISGUISED-HOST|
  X-SITE-DEPLOYMENT-ID|X-Original-URL|X-Forwarded-For|X-ARR-SSL|X-ARR-ClientCert
```

Both a client certificate directly from the request and the expected `X-ARR-ClientCert` header.

**UPDATE 4**: In the end this happened to be my own mistake (of course). I was convinced that the url for the backend was `https` while in fact it was `http`. Client certificate authentication only works over https so in hindsight it made perfect sense no certificate was found in the backend...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you really want to manage client certificates for all users of the API?  I understand using a client-cert to ensure only APIM can talk directly to your backend API.  Usually developers who expose APIs via API Management use API keys to control access to the API.  Using this approach enables policies to be applied based on different configured "products".

If you have the infrastructure in place to manage cert creation and revocation then this might be the right choice, it is just an uncommon approach.  Having said that I will investigate what options are available in API Management to be able to extract the certificate thumbprint on the APIM gateway.

Comment: I'm already using subscription keys to give developers access to products. The problem is between APIM and my actual API. I'm using a client cert to authenticate APIM against my actual API, works great. However, this still isn't of much use when anyone with a client-authentication-certificate can still access my actual API.

So the question is: how to retrieve the client-cert that APIM sends *in my actual API*.

If you can shed some light on that, great!! :)

Comment: @RonaldWildenberg Aha!  Now I understand.  Here is a delegating handler to do that http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001708/ch15.html#example_ch15_cert_handler

Comment: I already tried using `HttpRequestMessage.GetClientCertificate`. This one always returns `null`. The actual API is an Azure website so it sits behind a load-balancer. From my understanding, the client certificate should be in the `X-ARR-ClientCert` request header.

Comment: I added some additional code and log output to my question, demonstrating that `HttpRequestMessage.GetClientCertificate` doesn't work for me.

Comment: @RonaldWildenberg Ok, that is strange. I will try and repro and get someone on the team to take a look.

Comment: Ok, thanks in advance! I added additional logging of what happens when I go to my actual API directly. Then it works as expected.

Comment: Any news on this? I now implemented a shared secret between APIM and API so the API can not be accessed by just anyone. This works but I prefer client-authentication-certificates.

Comment: @RonaldWildenberg Sorry, I've been away at a conference for the last few days.  I've escalated the issue now.

Comment: @DarrelMiller: Any update on this issue from your end ? Thanks!

Comment: @Pickle  The certificate comes through ok if you make sure your URL to the backend API is an HTTPs url.  You should be able to use Request.GetClientCertificate()

Answer (score 5):

You also need to enable client certificate authentication for the Azure hosted API - this step will ensure Azure carries over any X-ARR-ClientCert headers coming on the incoming request.

**Otherwise Azure removes the X-ARR-ClientCert header from Request.Headers before it reaches your API.**

Note:  this setup is only available for paid subscriptions

1. Go to https://resources.azure.com/  and select your desired azure account
2. Select subscriptions -> resource groups -> your_resource_group -> providers -> microsoft.web -> sites -> your_website
3. Enter in Read/Write mode from top button, enter in Edit mode then set the  property "clientCertEnabled": true under properties.

> ```
> "properties": {
>     "name": "my-site",
>     "state": "Running",
>     "hostNames": [
>       "my-site.azurewebsites.net",
>       "(string)"
>     ],
>     ...
>     "clientCertEnabled": true,
>     ...
>  }
> ```

Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-web-configure-tls-mutual-auth

Answer (score 1):

I am contacting the engineers in APIM to figure out how this is intended to work and will get back to you. When you have APIM in front of your actual API (web app), my guess is that APIM is the proxy that will take care of all the authN / authZ for you. So requests would go to your API only when this succeeds. I am guessing that is why they probably just drop the client certificate instead of forwarding it onward. But I can definitely see why the client cert would still be useful in the web app.

Comment: Thanks for the really quick response!! I wonder if it really works as you describe. My API is actually requiring a client certificate. How can APIM just bypass this and not send the certificate? My API could have been running in AWS instead of Azure, how would it work then? I'm very curious about the answer :)

Comment: @RonaldWildenberg If APIM is calling your backend successfully then it is using the cert.  The cert gets passed at the TCP layer below HTTP so you will not see the cert being passed in the request.  I'm guessing the X-ARR-ClientCert header you are seeing is due to ARR stripping information out of the client cert and copying it to the header.  I need to confirm this but I suspect when you go via APIM you are not going via ARR so there is nothing to strip out this cert info.  I'll investigate what mechanisms exist for in APIM for extract the cert info .

Comment: I added some of the code that I'm using and the resulting log output. The result I consistently get is that when APIM calls my actual API, I cannot find the certificate that APIM must be using to call my API...